# using input from file to define colour of bar in plot (matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot a bar diagram using input from a .csv file.

My input file contains several columns with sample names and data and also a column with the colour of my sample. This column contains strings, such as 'w' meaning white, 'b' meaning brown and so forth. Each line contains values for a different sample.

Now I want the bar for each sample to have the colour specified in the colour column.

My code looks a bit like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

results_dtype=np.dtype([('name', 'S100'), ('colour', 'S10'),
('data_this', 'float64'), ('data_that', 'float64'), ...])


data = np.genfromtxt('C:/data.csv', delimiter = ',', dtype =results_dtype, filling_values=np.nan, skip_header=1)

colours = {'w':'#FFFFFF',
'y':'#ffff00',
'b':'#cc8033',
'p':'#CC79A7'}

fig = plt.figure()
plt.bar(np.arange(len(data)), data['data_this'], bottom=data['data_that'], align='center', color=colours[data['colour']])
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(data)), data['name'], rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

The error message I get is the following:

> unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' (pointing to the plt.bar(...) line).

It sounds like I'm calling the dictionary the wrong way or something along those lines but I can't figure out how to do it properly.

I hope, this is explains what I'm trying to do.

Comment: it just gives me the same error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `dict`s can only be indexed with a single key.  They don't allow "vectorized" indexing.

Let's use a simplified example that gives the same error:

```
import numpy as np

lookup = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
values = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a'])
data = lookup[values]
```

Which yields:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-7d8663a08b8d> in <module>()
      1 lookup = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
      2 values = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a'])
----> 3 data = lookup[values]

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

The exact error is because we're trying to use a mutable type as a key to the dict.  There are sequences (e.g. `tuple`s) that you could use as a key, but they still wouldn't work in the way that you want them to.

Therefore, instead of using a sequence of keys such as `data = lookup[values]`, you'll need to use a list comprehension:

```
data = [lookup[item] for item in values]
```

Putting this back into your original example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

results_dtype=np.dtype([('name', 'S100'), ('colour', 'S10'),
('data_this', 'float64'), ('data_that', 'float64'), ...])


data = np.genfromtxt('C:/data.csv', delimiter = ',', dtype=results_dtype, 
                     filling_values=np.nan, skip_header=1)

colours = {'w':'#FFFFFF',
           'y':'#ffff00',
           'b':'#cc8033',
           'p':'#CC79A7'}

color = [colours[item] for item in data['colour']]

fig = plt.figure()
plt.bar(np.arange(len(data)), data['data_this'], bottom=data['data_that'],  
        align='center', color=color)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(data)), data['name'], rotation='vertical')
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply! Problem solved and I'm happy! :)